# Difference between bash-shell and ksh-shell by using while with read - what can I do in bash for the same response as in ksh?

Tags: command-line, bash, ksh

I have two scripts:

1. in bash

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   H_VARIABLE=empty
   echo "Zeile1
         Zeile2" |
   while read satz
    do 
     H_VARIABLE="$H_VARIABLE $satz"
   done
   echo H_VARIABLE=$H_VARIABLE
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   H_VARIABLE=empty
   ```
2. in ksh

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/ksh
   H_VARIABLE=leer
   echo "Zeile1
         Zeile2" |
   while read satz
    do
     H_VARIABLE="$H_VARIABLE $satz"
   done
   echo H_VARIABLE=$H_VARIABLE
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   H_VARIABLE=leer Zeile1 Zeile2
   ```

Conclusion: `leer Zeile1 Zeile2` != `leer`

What can I do in bash to get the same response as in ksh?

Comment: In addition to steeldriver's answer which is correct, you might want to have a look at bash debugging tools like `shellcheck` you can find its homepage [here](http://www.shellcheck.net/). Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that, in bash, the `while` loop gets executed in a subshell when it is on the RHS of a pipe. You could do instead

```
H_VARIABLE=leer
while read satz
  do H_VARIABLE="$H_VARIABLE $satz"
done < <(
echo "Zeile1
      Zeile2"
)
```

using process substitution or, using a *here string*

```
H_VARIABLE=leer
while read satz
  do H_VARIABLE="$H_VARIABLE $satz"
done <<< "Zeile1
          Zeile2"
```

See also [bash script var not changed after the loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98579/bash-script-var-not-changed-after-the-loop?)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, them has helped me very much